# AngularJS Logout on close or refresh - REST services calls get cancelled

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have a problem here. I need to implement a logout on close or refresh, meaning when the customer navigates away from the web page, or closes browser/tab. I created a directive which is added to my forms, and which should call logout functionality (which includes the REST-call to our backend, which would trigger the Siteminder logout). The REST call is sometimes performed, but mainly gets cancelled. The console.log message nearly never appears.

```
.directive('gcdmAutomaticLogoutOnClose', function($rootScope, 
             $window, MyLoginService){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: true,
  controller: function($element){
    $window.onbeforeunload = function (){
      return MyLoginService.logout().then(function(){
        console.log("Logout complete");
        return null;
      });

    }}

  }

});
```

Any idea?

Comment: But did you suppose that onbeforeunload would wait logout to get resolved? Once it is resolved, why would also wait the callback to be ended?

Comment: Thats probably the reason. But, any idea how to do it right?

Comment: I am not sure if onbeforeunload waits a promise. But if it does, just create another promise, and resolve it within the success callback of logout promise; and make onbeforeunload wait that second promise.

Answer (score 1):

Your logout service should run synchronously (not return a promise) if you want to guarantee it will execute before the page unloads.

Angular's $http service runs async by design, but [here's a link showing how to make a synchronous service:](http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AUuADQO5a5vEqxqlK5mz/how-to-create-synchronous-using-http-in-angular-js.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to adapt the code from your link, but it still does not block... My controller now:
          var task1 = $q.defer();
          task1.promise.then(function(value){
            console.log("Start complete");
          } ,function(value){
            console.log("failed to logout")
          });

          LoginTimeoutService.logout().then(function(){
            console.log("Logout complete");
            task1.resolve();
          });

          $q.all([task1.promise]).then(
            function(){
              console.log("all complete");
            }
          );